# C++ Adobe Premiere video filter - print/draw/render text in output video frame

Tags: c++, plugins, adobe, video-processing, adobe-premiere

I want to write video filter for Adobe Premiere, and I need to print/draw/render some text into the output video frame.

Looking into [adobe premiere cs4 sdk](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/premiere/sdk/cs4/) I couldn't find a quick answer - is it possible?

Please provide some samples!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some strategy I will try to implement:

1. draw text with GDI into bitmap of frame size (VideoHandle->piSuites->ppixFuncs->ppixGetBounds)
2. overlap frame pixels (VideoHandle->source) with bitmap pixels

**UPDATE**
[alt text http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/6201/adobe.jpg](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/6201/adobe.jpg)
Working sample, using Simple_Video_Filter sample from SDK...

at the beginning of xFilter (short selector, VideoHandle theData) function create bitmap with text:

```
TCHAR szBuffer[50] = {0};
RECT rect;
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
int iLength = 0;
iLength = wsprintf(szBuffer, "Hello World!");
BITMAPINFO bmInfo;
memset(&bmInfo.bmiHeader,0,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
bmInfo.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth=100;
bmInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight=15;
bmInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes=1;
bmInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
//create a temporary dc in memory.
HDC pDC = GetDC(0);
HDC TmpDC=CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
//create a new bitmap and select it in the memory dc
BYTE *pbase;
HBITMAP TmpBmp=CreateDIBSection(pDC, &bmInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void**)&pbase,0,0);
HGDIOBJ TmpObj=SelectObject(TmpDC,TmpBmp);
SetRect(&rect, 0, 0, 100, 15);
DrawText(TmpDC, szBuffer, iLength, &rect, 32);
```

in the middle where filter is set, instead of

```
redSource = (redSource + redAdd) & 0x000000ff;
greenSource = (greenSource + greenAdd) & 0x000000ff;
blueSource = (blueSource + blueAdd) & 0x000000ff;
```

use

```
int x = vert;
int y = horiz;
if(x < 215 && y < 300)
{
    COLORREF c = GetPixel(TmpDC,y-200, 215 - x);
    if(0 == ((int)GetRValue(c)+(int)GetGValue(c)+(int)GetBValue(c)))
    {
        redSource =255;
        greenSource =255;
        blueSource =255;
    }
}
```

and in the end of function clean memory

```
SelectObject(TmpDC,TmpObj);
DeleteDC(TmpDC);
```

PS [some day :)] need to store bitmap in memory once instead of creating each time per frame...

Comment: такое впечатления что такие "задачи" только и аутсорсить) т. е. где нету онлайн документации/кучи примеров/не продуманная архитектура) пс делал тоже плагин для премер про)) с апворка брал заказ)